# Как привязать активити к фрагменту

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Я еще новичок и насовсем понимаю как привязать активити к фрагменту? У меня есть buttom menu ( Именно нижняя) и в одном из фрагментов я хочу реализовать чат, но сделал отдельное активити от фрагмента, теперь не пойму как привязать это, фрагмент у меня пустой. При копирование кода с Активити в фрагмент выходит куча ошибок

Comment: Слишком сложно дать ответ. Судя по вопросу вам надо в ответе описать исчерпывающе отличие активити от фрагментов. Это долго, сложно, проще в документации прочитать. Возможно, если вы локализуете проблему и зададите менее обширный вопрос, то получится дать ответ длинной менее пары тысяч строк. Например приведите код который не работает с описанием что именно не работает - поможем.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб лучше всего в фрагмент код бросать как я понял? чем привязывать отдельное активити?

Comment: Я еще так тупанул, я сделал навигацию на котлине, а чат на java пишу, это так себе затея? Лучше всего переписать навигацию на Java? простите за куча вопросов... у меня дипломная работа, а я не успеваю(

Comment: Всё делать на фрагментах и иметь только одну активити, которая эти фрагменты отображает - рекомендация гугла и общеприменительная практика. Смешивать языки можно, но лучше всё на котлине писать, хотя бы потому, что это удобнее и приятнее

Comment: Спасибо за совет, в итоге я удалил лишний активити и около двух часов не могу понять как этот код встроить в fragment, вроде сделал чтобы хотябы ошибки сразу не вылетали, запускаю эмулятор перехожу на этот фграгмент и у меня сразу же вылетает

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я же правильно все понял? Код нужно писать именно в отдельном фрагменте, а не в общем активити ( который соединяет все фрагменты)

Comment: Да, идея такая. Всё логика во фрагментах, активити только отображает фрагменты

Comment: Если что-то не работает и падает - приведите проблемный код и лог ошибки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб получилось решить самому проблемный промежуток, только вот один вопрос все же, куда мне писать проблему? Сюда или создать новое обсуждение? у меня просто еще немного ошибок осталось, где-то 2-3 из 11 :)

Comment: Идея сайта - одна проблема - один вопрос. Т.е, если у вас 3 проблемы - надо 3 вопроса. Наверное, в вашем случае лучше новый вопрос задать, а в этом в ответе самому написать хоть что-то из того что помогло решить часть проблем)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб хорошо, спасибо большое, ответы на решения напишу позже как все получится до конца, вопросы задал